# Problem cloning a BitBucket repo using SSH

Tags: git, bitbucket

Hello stackoverflow community,

N.B.: when I use the HTTPS, it works.

So my problem is the following:

whenever I want to clone a repo from a bitbucket using SSH, it shows me an error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Let me explain how I did it:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "mymail@domain.com"`

I got a folder `.ssh` which contains the private and the public key.

Next I copied the public key into my account setting > SSH Keys.

After that: I executed the following commands:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/path/to/id_rsa
```

now when I execute
`git clone "ssh/repo"` I got the problem mentioned before.

how to solve this please?

Comment: What was the output from sub-step 8 of step 3? (Note: `exec ssh-agent bash` is almost certainly wrong here. See sub-step 1 of step 2.) https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Bitbucket about your ssh key.  I think you have done everything but `Step 3. Add the public key to your Account settings` from the below reference link, but you may want to go through it step by step just in case.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Comment: I already done it! 
```Next I copied the public key into my account setting > SSH Keys```